# Need help connecting Websocket in spring to a database

Tags: database, spring, spring-boot

I need help with connecting my WebSocket to my DB in spring boot.

I know that the DB access happens in the controller but I don't know how.

```
@Controller
public class ChatController {

    @MessageMapping("/chat.register")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage register(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
        headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", chatMessage.getSender());
        return chatMessage;

    }

    @MessageMapping("/chat.send")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage sendMessage(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        return chatMessage;
    } 

}
```

Where would I connect to the DB

Comment: Is your database already set up? And are you using `@Repository` or a direct connection?

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to add a repository to your controller. A better approach is to add a service layer between controller and database.

```
@Controller
public class ChatController {

@Autowired
private Chatservice chatservice;

    @MessageMapping("/chat.register")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage register(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
        headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", chatMessage.getSender());
        chatservice.saveChatMessage(chatMessage); // save this too?
        return chatMessage;

    }

    @MessageMapping("/chat.send")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage sendMessage(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        chatservice.saveChatMessage(chatMessage);
        return chatMessage;
    } 

}

@Service
private class ChatService {

@Autowired
private ChatRepository repository;

public void saveChatMessage(ChatMessage chatMessage) {
  // do more business stuff here e.g. Mapping to Entity ....
  repository.save(chatMessage);
}

}

public interface ChatRepository extends CrudRepository<ChatMessage, Long>  {
}
```